# Jquery - Assign array values to dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have dropdowns that are being appended dynamically on a page and on the same page, there's an array being posted, so that, the length of the array will always equal the number of dropdowns appended. For example:

```
<select name="cavie" class="optimum"><option value=""></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option></select>

<select name="cavie" class="optimum"><option value=""></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option></select>

<select name="cavie" class="optimum"><option value=""></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option></select>
```

and a javascript array:

```
var vals = ["4", "8", "12"];
```

The aim is to assign the array values to the dropdowns in their order.

Currently, I'm using a `for` loop but this will set all the select options to the value of the last array:

```
var vals = ["4", "8", "12"];

for(var i in vals)
{
    $('.optimum').val(vals[i]); 
}
```

The above is laid out in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/epzjdswn/2/

So how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to select the element based on index as well, otherwise you set the value of the first item in the collection on every iteration.

You can do that using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), and you could replace the `for` loop with jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
var vals = ["4", "8", "12"];

$.each(vals, function(i, val) {
    $('.optimum').eq(i).val(val);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/epzjdswn/11/)

There's also the option to do it the other way around, and iterate over elements instead *(using a little ES2015 for dramatic effect)*

```
var vals = ["4", "8", "12"];
$('.optimum').val(i => vals[i]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/epzjdswn/14/)

Comment: Great. one final one: how would go about setting the selected value to the attibute `selected`? something along the lines: `$('select[name=cavie] option[value='+?+']').prop('selected', true);` is what i'm thinking

Comment: The `selected` property is set on the option, but setting the value of the select does the same thing, so you shouldn't really have to set the `selected` property at all. If you really want to, it would be like -> https://jsfiddle.net/epzjdswn/26/

Comment: Excellent. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that the *index* `#each()` funtion called on `.optimum` will be the *index* of the `vals` array - see demo below:

```js
var vals = ["4", "8", "12"];
$('.optimum').each(function(i) {
  $(this).val(vals[i])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="cavie" class="optimum"><option value=""></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option></select>

<select name="cavie" class="optimum"><option value=""></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option></select>

<select name="cavie" class="optimum"><option value=""></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to target that specific select, instead you are targeting all selects with the `optimum` class, just use the `eq` function to target the specific select.

```
var vals = ["4", "8", "12"];
for(var i in vals){
  $('.optimum').eq(i).val(vals[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var vals = ["4", "8", "12"];

for(var i in vals)
{
    $('.optimum:nth-child(' + (+i + 1) + ')').val(vals[i]); 
}
```